# Detect a certain Object in a video stream

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am trying to detect a white Object on a black/white road to let an autonmous RC car drive around it. And i am detecting everything but the white box on the road.

What I tried can be seen in my code Example

```py
#input= one video stream frame 320x240
frame = copy.deepcopy(input)
grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshGray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
            grayFrame,
            255,
            cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,
            blockSize=123,
            C=-19,
        )
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(threshGray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:

   #some filtering needs to be done
   #
   #after filtering append contour

   filteredContours.append(cnt)
   cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (3, 244, 244), 1)

cv2.drawContours(frame, filteredContours, -1, (255, 0, 255),1 )
cv2.imshow("with contours", frame)
cv2.imshow("adaptiveThreshhold", threshGray)
cv2.imshow("input", input)
```

I'm looking for a way to draw a bounding box around the obstacle.
Problem is I dont know how to extract this box from the rest.
It is probably because the contour of the box and the lines on the right are connected and thats why the bounding box is that big. Would be great if someone knows a way to do that.

Click here to see the Result

[image]

First: Input image

Second: after adaptiveThreshold

third: with contours(pink) and bounding boxes(yellow)

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, you got several candidates of white color value.

You need to add code in to the `#some filtering needs to be done` to rid candidate list of NOT bounding box you want to find.

I suggest you to compare your candidate list with square box as bigger as enough.

Because all of contours without BOX(that you want to find on the road) do not satisfy condition about square box as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is triangular masking, as seen in the input image you have lane marking as well. Did try using a lane detector with this all the areas out of lane can be masked and only the spaces in lane can be processed.

Below I have tried to use Lane detector using HoughLinesP and added Contours as well. Try to use this, I did not test this code but I see no issues.

---

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 3
"""
Lane detector using the Hog transform method
"""
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rng

rng.seed(369)

def do_canny(frame):
    # Converts frame to grayscale because we only need the luminance channel for detecting edges - less computationally expensive
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    # Applies a 5x5 gaussian blur with deviation of 0 to frame - not mandatory since Canny will do this for us
    blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    # Applies Canny edge detector with minVal of 50 and maxVal of 150
    canny = cv.Canny(blur, 50, 150)
    return canny

def do_segment(frame):
    # Since an image is a multi-directional array containing the relative intensities of each pixel in the image, we can use frame.shape to return a tuple: [number of rows, number of columns, number of channels] of the dimensions of the frame
    # frame.shape[0] give us the number of rows of pixels the frame has. Since height begins from 0 at the top, the y-coordinate of the bottom of the frame is its height
    height = frame.shape[0]
    # Creates a triangular polygon for the mask defined by three (x, y) coordinates
    polygons = np.array([
                            [(0, height), (800, height), (380, 290)]
                        ])
    # Creates an image filled with zero intensities with the same dimensions as the frame
    mask = np.zeros_like(frame)
    # Allows the mask to be filled with values of 1 and the other areas to be filled with values of 0
    cv.fillPoly(mask, polygons, 255)
    # A bitwise and operation between the mask and frame keeps only the triangular area of the frame
    segment = cv.bitwise_and(frame, mask)
    return segment

def calculate_lines(frame, lines):
    # Empty arrays to store the coordinates of the left and right lines
    left = []
    right = []
    # Loops through every detected line
    for line in lines:
        # Reshapes line from 2D array to 1D array
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
        # Fits a linear polynomial to the x and y coordinates and returns a vector of coefficients which describe the slope and y-intercept
        parameters = np.polyfit((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 1)
        slope = parameters[0]
        y_intercept = parameters[1]
        # If slope is negative, the line is to the left of the lane, and otherwise, the line is to the right of the lane
        if slope < 0:
            left.append((slope, y_intercept))
        else:
            right.append((slope, y_intercept))
    # Averages out all the values for left and right into a single slope and y-intercept value for each line
    left_avg = np.average(left, axis = 0)
    right_avg = np.average(right, axis = 0)
    # Calculates the x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates for the left and right lines
    left_line = calculate_coordinates(frame, left_avg)
    right_line = calculate_coordinates(frame, right_avg)
    return np.array([left_line, right_line])

def calculate_coordinates(frame, parameters):
    slope, intercept = parameters
    # Sets initial y-coordinate as height from top down (bottom of the frame)
    y1 = frame.shape[0]
    # Sets final y-coordinate as 150 above the bottom of the frame
    y2 = int(y1 - 150)
    # Sets initial x-coordinate as (y1 - b) / m since y1 = mx1 + b
    x1 = int((y1 - intercept) / slope)
    # Sets final x-coordinate as (y2 - b) / m since y2 = mx2 + b
    x2 = int((y2 - intercept) / slope)
    return np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2])

def visualize_lines(frame, lines):
    # Creates an image filled with zero intensities with the same dimensions as the frame
    lines_visualize = np.zeros_like(frame)
    # Checks if any lines are detected
    if lines is not None:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines:
            # Draws lines between two coordinates with green color and 5 thickness
            cv.line(lines_visualize, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 5)
    return lines_visualize

# The video feed is read in as a VideoCapture object
cap = cv.VideoCapture(1)
while (cap.isOpened()):
    # ret = a boolean return value from getting the frame, frame = the current frame being projected in the video
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    canny = do_canny(frame)
    cv.imshow("canny", canny)
    # plt.imshow(frame)
    # plt.show()
    segment = do_segment(canny)
    hough = cv.HoughLinesP(segment, 2, np.pi / 180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength = 100, maxLineGap = 50)
    # Averages multiple detected lines from hough into one line for left border of lane and one line for right border of lane
    lines = calculate_lines(frame, hough)
    # Visualizes the lines
    lines_visualize = visualize_lines(frame, lines)
    cv.imshow("hough", lines_visualize)
    # Overlays lines on frame by taking their weighted sums and adding an arbitrary scalar value of 1 as the gamma argument
    output = cv.addWeighted(frame, 0.9, lines_visualize, 1, 1)
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(output, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    contours_poly = [None]*len(contours)
    boundRect = [None]*len(contours)
    centers = [None]*len(contours)
    radius = [None]*len(contours)
    for i, c in enumerate(contours):
        contours_poly[i] = cv.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
        boundRect[i] = cv.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
        centers[i], radius[i] = cv.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i])
    ## [allthework]

    ## [zeroMat]
    drawing = np.zeros((output.shape[0], output.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    ## [zeroMat]

    ## [forContour]
    # Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects + circles
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
        cv.drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color)
        cv.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
          (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)

    # Opens a new window and displays the output frame
    cv.imshow('Contours', drawing)
    # Frames are read by intervals of 10 milliseconds. The programs breaks out of the while loop when the user presses the 'q' key
    if cv.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
# The following frees up resources and closes all windows
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

try different values in the threshold for canny.

Comment: To understand more about Lane detector read it in webpage here- https://towardsdatascience.com/tutorial-build-a-lane-detector-679fd8953132

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your solution